# Is it a bad practice to handle client's web page / static files requests and REST API requests on the same express server?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, server

I've got a web app (single page React app) and I have an express server hosted on cloud run that handles all of my users' requests.

But I have some `/api` routes which right now are being handled on the same server. They usually call an external API or update something in the database.

For example:

```
/api/send-contact      // SENDS CONTACT FORM EMAIL
/api/search            // HANDLES TEXT SEARCH AND RESPONDS
/api/update-viewcount  // UPDATES THE DB VIEW COUNT FOR A PAGE
```

Is it a bad practice to handle those `/api` calls on the same `express` server that I use to respond to user's page requests? Should I build a separate server just for those "API" calls?

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not really sure. Maybe performance issues? Or maybe it will mess up the metrics that I could use to analyze my server's health? Ex: users requests usually are responded really quickly, and a `/api/search` request will take longer. Is it common for people to handle both on the same server?

Comment: Truthfully I don't know. :-) I think I'd worry about those problems if/when I had them, but that's just an off-the-cuff view and not one based in wide experience of this specific question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server architecture contains many tradeoffs.  To get higher scale, you typically add complexity (server clustering, offloading static resources, dynamically spinning up more servers, etc...).  But, you don't want to add unnecessary complexity as that may cost more and is more complicated to manage and monitor and maintain.

So, offloading static resources to some other server (a CDN or an NGINX instance or something like that) is one path on the road to adding scale to your server.  But, you would only go there when you have a specific server scalability motivation for doing so.  If your server is operating at 30% capacity now, there's no reason to go there yet.

> Is it a bad practice to handle those /api calls on the same express server that I use to respond to user's page requests?

No.  Not if your server is able to handle your current load just fine.

> Should I build a separate server just for those "API" calls?

No.  When you need more server scale and you've finished doing simple server optimizations to improve your scale, then you would consider getting some things off your API server such as serving static resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still thinking of separating the servers in favor of "separation of concerns". It will be easier to monitor logs and response times of my pages/static files server (I already have a CDN from Firebase Hosting, but I also do SSR for robots and my SSR responses are not cached). The API related code will be on a separate folder and I'll get to deploy them separately, which is nice.

Comment: @cbdeveloper - Keep in mind that if the top level web page comes from a different server than you are making API calls to, then you will have to deal with cross origin restrictions.  That can be managed, but it is some extra work.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Firebase Hosting allows me to rewrite each route to a different server. So, from the browser's perspective, I will still be requesting `mydomain.com/api`. That would handle the CORS issue, right?

Comment: @cbdeveloper - Yes, if the browser is requesting pages from the same host, port and protocol as the page was loaded from, then no CORs restrictions.  If it happens to get proxied to some other server, that will be entirely unknown to the browser.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks a lot for your help on this topic.